# Cual es el proceso del token una ves autorizado

Tags: backend, tokens

Tengo una duda del lado del servidor, estoy creando una api y es la primera ves que me toca implementar token en header de `Authorization`. Pero... que proceso se sigue para esto? es decir, recibo el token de usuario y lo busco en la lista de tokens registrados y proceder a ejecutar alguna funciona, etc... esto es correcto?
Me gustaría conocer el siclo de vida de esto.

Comment: jwt, otro tipo de hmac o alguna combinación de crypt+hash?

Comment: ? no comprendí o no entendiste mi pregunta creo